# XmlSerializer - There was an error reflecting type - error deserializing

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have an error when trying to deserialize an xml
I have a set of classes that are prepared to receive this xml:

```
<raiz>
    <propiedad1>
        <p1></p1>
        <p2>
            <p21></p21>
            <p22></p22>
        </p2>
    </propiedad1>
</raiz>
```

But, if my code receives an XML that don't include  tag then I get the following exception: "There was an error reflecting type p2"

this is my code to deserialize:

```
var obj = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Y));
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show your classes?

Comment: Make sure `Y` and all referenced classes have a [public default constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  Beyond that we can't help much unless you show us your classes or the full `ToString()` output of the exception.